# Theorem 10.9 Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> **Theorem 10.9**
>   Suppose $T$ is a $1-1$ $C^{1}$ mapping of an open set $E \subset \Bbb R^{n}$ into $ \Bbb R^{k}$ such that $J_{T}(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in E$. If $f$ is a continuous function on $\Bbb R^{k}$ whose support is compact and lies in $T(E)$, then $$\int_{R^k}{f(y)dy}=\int_{R^k}{f(T(\mathbf{x}))\left\lvert J_T(\mathbf{x})\right\rvert d\mathbf{x}}$$

My question is that, why do we need to specify the support of $f$ is compact? Can we just say the domain of $f$ lies in $T(x)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The integrals may not make sense without compact support. (Of course, you don't mean "lies in $T(x)$.")

Comment: This result is still true if $f$ is continuous and integrable, but to prove the more general version you will first find a $f_K$ with compact support and at $L^1$ distance from $f$ less than $\varepsilon.$